# tcsetpgrp's enigmatic behavior in this very short program in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork, jobs

This is the program full code in 2 versions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid){
        setpgid(pid, pid);
        tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, pid);
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        puts("waitdone");
        //in second version: uncomment the next line
        //tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, getpgrp());
        while(1);
    }else{
        //child
        while(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 questions for 2 versions of the program

1. After run first version program, then press `ctrl-c`, it prints out `waitdone`. The following `ctrl-c` does not interrupt main process -> program stuck, could not be broken by `ctrl-c` anymore. Why did the shell not ignore parent process and return to prompt right after first `ctrl-c` while the parent process is not in foreground anymore?
2. In the second version (with second `tcsetpgrp` uncomment), after first `ctrl-c`, the parent process seem to be stopped by `sigtstp`.
   Shell prints out `'./a.out' has stopped` and returns to the prompt.
   After that, main program can be restored with `fg`. This time, `ctrl-c` stops parent process's `while(1);`. Why in the second version, parent process's`tcsetpgrp` does not blocks shell to return to the prompt?

PS: I'm implementing a mini shell. After being taken lots of time for researching and debugging, I reduced my code to this short program.

Please help.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: **Ad 1**. I wonder if this may have anything to do with following explanation: "The foreground job may have left the terminal in a strange state, so the shell should restore its own saved terminal modes before continuing." [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Foreground-and-Background.html)